# BeutifulSoup webscraping dental forum targeting titles

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a forum to generate a dataset for analysis.

when selecting the topic the class name has a trailing unique number like:

How could I scrape and return a list of strings containing all the class names like:

```
["structItem structItem--thread js-inlineModContainer js-threadListItem-00001", 
"structItem structItem--thread js-inlineModContainer js-threadListItem-00394", 
"structItem structItem--thread js-inlineModContainer js-threadListItem-00045"...]
```

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.dentistry-forums.com/forums/periodontics.11/"
result = requests.get(url).text
doc = BeautifulSoup(result, "html.parser")
bbody = doc.body
bbody = bbody.find('div', attrs={'class':"p-pageWrapper"})
bbody = bbody.find('div', attrs={'class':"p-body"})
bbody = bbody.find('div', attrs={'class':"p-body-inner"})
bbody = bbody.find('div', attrs={'class':"p-body-main"})
bbody = bbody.find('div', attrs={'class':"p-body-content"})
bbody = bbody.find('div', attrs={'class':"p-body-pageContent"})
bbody = bbody.find('div', attrs={'class':"block"})
bbody = bbody.find('div', attrs={'class':"block-container"})
bbody = bbody.find('div', attrs={'class':"block-body"})
bbody = bbody.find('div', attrs={'class':"structItemContainer"})
bbody = bbody.find('div', attrs={'class':"structItemContainer-group js-threadList"})
print(bbody.prettify())
```

Comment: I am not getting and error I am just trying to figure out how to extract the sections that I want from the output.

Answer (score 2):

To get the titles of threads, their URLs and classnames you can use next example:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.dentistry-forums.com/forums/periodontics.11/"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

for a in soup.select(".structItem-title a"):
    class_names = " ".join(
        a.find_previous(attrs={"data-author": True})["class"]
    )

    print("Title:", a.text)
    print("URL:", "https://www.dentistry-forums.com" + a["href"])
    print("Classnames:", class_names)
    print()
```

Prints:

```
...

Title: Deep Cleaning
URL: https://www.dentistry-forums.com/threads/deep-cleaning.26561/
Classnames: structItem structItem--thread js-inlineModContainer js-threadListItem-26561

Title: Deep Cleaning Charges
URL: https://www.dentistry-forums.com/threads/deep-cleaning-charges.26548/
Classnames: structItem structItem--thread js-inlineModContainer js-threadListItem-26548

Title: Advanced GD and loose teeth
URL: https://www.dentistry-forums.com/threads/advanced-gd-and-loose-teeth.26519/
Classnames: structItem structItem--thread js-inlineModContainer js-threadListItem-26519

Title: Recurrent thrush centered around one tooth
URL: https://www.dentistry-forums.com/threads/recurrent-thrush-centered-around-one-tooth.26513/
Classnames: structItem structItem--thread js-inlineModContainer js-threadListItem-26513
```